# Can we chant nama to benefit others?

Tags: mantras, japa, nama-japa

This is a bit of a basic question, but can we chant and broadcast the benefit to others? For example, can one chant the name of Rama and give the spiritual and material benefits to another instead of oneself? When I do nama japa, I tend not to ask for anything for myself, and do it only as a service to God, but lately I have seen the sufferings of others and feel compelled to help. However, one can only do so much physically, so I feel compelled to offer more help in a spiritual form.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want others to derive health and other benefits from your japa then while chanting just keep a pot of water in front of you. After the completion of the japa this water will be infused with the potency of the nama/mantra. Then this water can be sprinkled on the other person's head or can be consumed by him/her. Another method is to take a Sankalpa before the japa to declare that the fruits of the japa should be awarded to a specific person.